# Can I run a userscript on the new tab page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey, userscripts

I have a very simple userscript that I've written with TamperMonkey, and I'd like it to run on the Chrome new tab page.

According to [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126193540/https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=725) there is no way to run userscripts on the new tab page:

> The URL of the new tab page is "chrome://newtab/" and Chrome doesn't allow extensions to inject scripts into that pages.

But my script runs fine if I specify in the header section

```
// @match        *://*/*
```

to match all pages. Still, I'd rather the code only ran on the new tab page, is this possible?

---

Full script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide Buttons
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Test script
// @author       Greedo
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function(window, chrome) {
    "use strict";
    var doc = window.document;
    doc.getElementById("mv-tiles").style.opacity = "0";
    doc.getElementById("f").style.opacity = "0.1";
}(window, chrome));
```

I'm using Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115.

Comment: 1. mv-tiles is inside an iframe with chrome-search:// URL, and these URLs aren't scriptable 2. Chrome 61.0.3161 and newer explicitly forbid scripting of the new tab page, see https://crrev.com/2978953002/

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't entirely follow. If that element is "not scriptable", then how come my script does run with the current match pattern?

Comment: Fore pre-61 Chrome use `@match https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab*` or a regexp for all regional mirrrors

Comment: Here: https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=725

Comment: This no longer works as of 2020. The only option now is to create a browser extension that modifies your new tab page.

Answer (score 0):

Before the script loads, inside the code put the following requirement:

```
if(document.URL == 'chrome://new-tab-page/'){
    // Your user script code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `@match *://*/*` and printing the `window.location` you'll see that the `href` property does not contain `chrome://new-tab-page/` but `https://ogs.google.com/u/0/widget/app?origin=chrome-untrusted%3A%2F%2Fnew-tab-page&origin=chrome%3A%2F%2Fnew-tab-page&cn=app&pid=1&spid=243&hl=en` (in my case).

If I use `chrome://new-tab-page/` the script does not work but if the other URL is used it does actually work.

Here what I used to get the URL:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide Buttons
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Test script
// @author       Greedo
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    "use strict";
    console.log(window.location)
}());
```