# Is there a way to allow Tampermonkey to run on the chrome homepage?

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to make an extension using the right click menu. I noticed that the menu didn't display on the Chrome homepage because Tampermonkey didn't run on it. This is my current code:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Go to Website.Net
// @namespace       http://tampermonkey.net/
// @description     Context menu to execute UserScript
// @version         0.1
// @author          author
// @include         *
// @grant           GM_openInTab
// @run-at          context-menu
// ==/UserScript==]


(function() {
    'use strict';
    GM_openInTab("https://website.net");
})();
```

Is there a way to allow Tampermonkey to run on the chrome homepage?

Comment: Is "chrome homepage" the new tab page?

Comment: If this doesn't get answered here, you might have better luck asking on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @double-beep yes

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I run a userscript on the new tab page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45300745)